# Loop Phyton / Selenium

Tags: python

I have a piece of code in Pycharm , and I want to loop just a part of it, not with the beginning part where are located the login info. Let's say that I want to loop from the 44 line to 99 and only for 20 loops.

Comment: Hi Alex Alex. It's important for the replies to receive an "accepted" flag is you find them well-completed. If you find some of the answers give you the idea you were looking for, I'd suggest to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Before:

```
start = 1
multiply = start * 2
divided = multiply / 3
```

Now, let's say you want to multiply by two 20 times:

```
start = 1
multiply = multiply_value(value = start, number_of_times = 20)
divided = multiply / 3

def multiply_value(value, number_of_times):
   if(number_of_times <= 0):
      return value
   else:
      return multiply_value(value * 2, number_of_times - 1)
```

Alternatively, you could use a *for loop*:

```
def multiply_value(value, number_of_times):
       result = 1
       for i range(0, number_of_times):
           result = result * 2
       return result
```

I suggest reading the section 4 of [this Learn X in Y Minutes page](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/).

Answer (score 0):

Loops are well documented: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
```

Suggest you do some reading on Python fundamentals:

- https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops
- https://realpython.com/best-python-books/